# Time-invariant query for existing & non-existing user with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, redis, bcrypt

In my authentication service, I am trying to fetch password from my Redis with a simple `StringRedisTemplate` object.
 Then, I use `BCryptPasswordEncoder` for password matching.
I figured that there is a time difference between username mismatch to password mismatch.
I have read some articles that say username is not a secret value and I don't have to be worried about - I'm aware of that, but in my case I want to have no time difference between both cases.
How can I do that?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/auth", consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> isClientExists(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    //with redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(sha256Hex(userName)) :
    UserDetails user = redisClient.loadUserByUserName(user.getUserName()); 

    if (userNotFound(userFromDB)) {
        /* What should I add here to make it time-invariant query? */
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }
    if (!authenticateUser(user.getPassword(), userFromDB.getPassword())) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}

private boolean userNotFound(UserDetails userFromDB) {
    return (userFromDB == null);
}

private boolean authenticateUser(String userPassword, String userFromDBPassword) {
    //with BCryptPasswordEncoder :
    return passwordEncoder.matches(userPassword, userFromDBPassword);
}
```

Comment: Why do you implement login by yourself? Spring Security does it already. Don't bypass Spring Security. However, time to load user depends on database and should be equal for all usernames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches:

1) Figure out how long the authenticateUser call takes on average and sleep this long (though the time will probably change on a CPU upgrade in future).

2) Just make another authenticateUser call with random data and ignore the result.